# Shared Exchange Calendar from other user in sharepoint

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-calendar, exchange

I think it's classical problem that some users had. I want to create Share Point Calendar which can show and edit schedule for multiple user (other user than current log on). I can created shared Calendar I want in Outlook by creating shared calendar and granting permission to other user. Could we do this in Share point?

I have searched this question, and most of them said it not possible. Some of them said it is possible but cannot give proven solution. 
Could you give me proven solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can with limitations, but each user will have to put their day/schedule on this new SharePoint calendar linked in Outlook. It would have to replace the Calendar that they use. Each entry would have to be **manually** entered, and many automatic entries that Outlook does for you, such as meeting invites, will not be done automatically in the SharePoint calendar, it will still use the default calendar.

Why not publicly share the Outlook personal calendar for your team in Exchange? You can check all the calendars in your team and have the calendar entries overlay in Outlook..

Comment: Yeah, I've same opinion with you, but my boss want to do it in sophisticated way in Sharepoint. In the end we use calendar sharing feature in Outlook. Thank you for sharing.